# How to map a key/value array instead of an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, array.prototype.map

I need to get some value from some forms so when I need to call the specific value from a form I want to call for the particular key in an array. But `Array.prototype.map` creates an object with in index (0, 1, 2) and then stores the key/value, so I cannot access a particular value without knowing the index.

I tried array.push() and also the functions from [here](https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-object-exercise-15.php) which seems too much because I know there's a simpler way.

```
let extraClassArray = licenseClass
    .map( ( i, e ) => {
        if ( '' != $( e ).val() && e.hasAttribute( 'required' ) ) {
            let id = $( e ).data( 'parent' );
            let obj = {};
            switch ( $( e ).val() ) {
                case 'A':
                    obj.A =
                        '1' ===
                        $( '#license-class-' + id )
                            .find( '#license-class-' + id + '-a-value:checked' )
                            .val() ?
                            '1' :
                            '0';
                    break;
                case 'A2':
                    obj.A2 =
                        '1' ===
                        $( '#license-class-' + id )
                            .find( '#license-class-' + id + '-a2-value:checked' )
                            .val() ?
                            '1' :
                            '0';
                    break;
                case 'B':
                    obj.BF17 =
                        '1' ===
                        $( '#license-class-' + id )
                            .find(
                                '#license-class-' + id + '-bf17-value:checked'
                            )
                            .val() ?
                            '1' :
                            '0';
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return obj;
        }
    })
    .get();

console.log(extraClassArray);
```

I want to be able to cal for exapmple `extraClassArrat['A']` to get the value 0 or 1.

Comment: What array are you mapping? It looks like your question is missing some important code. Please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Daan I'm mapping values from different checkboxe on select option change.

Comment: Use `let obj = {};`, not `[]`.

Comment: @Bergi It's a typo I used {}. [] returns and empty array as I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is creating an array of arrays which have additional attributes A, A2, etc.

First of all, I think you are confused with the difference between arrays and objects and should read about it (maybe you are coming from PHP?)

What you should do in your case is create an object outside of your loop and assign its properties during the loop. So you should use foreach() and not map.

**Something like that:**

```
const extraClassArray = {};
licenseClass
.forEach( ( i, e ) => {
    if ( '' != $( e ).val() && e.hasAttribute( 'required' ) ) {
        let id = $( e ).data( 'parent' );
        switch ( $( e ).val() ) {
            case 'A':
                extraClassArray.A =
                    '1' ===
                    $( '#license-class-' + id )
                        .find( '#license-class-' + id + '-a-value:checked' )
                        .val() ?
                        '1' :
                        '0';
                break;
            case 'A2':
                extraClassArray.A2 =
                    '1' ===
                    $( '#license-class-' + id )
                        .find( '#license-class-' + id + '-a2-value:checked' )
                        .val() ?
                        '1' :
                        '0';
                break;
            case 'B':
                extraClassArray.BF17 =
                    '1' ===
                    $( '#license-class-' + id )
                        .find(
                            '#license-class-' + id + '-bf17-value:checked'
                        )
                        .val() ?
                        '1' :
                        '0';
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Yes I am coming from PHP. I do understand the difference though. Your solution seem viable, I'll try it.

Comment: I added an example, so you get the idea

Comment: Btw I kept map instead of your forEach, still works perfectly.

Comment: @AmirRami it still works but map returns a new array, whereas forEach doesn't return anything, so you should use forEach for this case

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple javascript object:

```
var obj = {
    key1: value1,
    key2: value2
};
```

Adding properties like this:

```
obj["key3"] = "value3";
```

And getting your values in this way:

```
var getProperty = function (propertyName) {
    return obj[propertyName];
};

getProperty("key1");
getProperty("key2");
getProperty("key3");
```

Comment: I need to input the values into the array dynamically, with a `switch`. So `Array.prototype.map` is a no go?